# how to extract the JSON data into javascript - data is in key value pair

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, arraylist

I want to extract the json data into javascript. Data is in key value pair.

Data is =

```
{09/02/2014 15:36:25=[33.82, 33.42, 40.83], 08/11/2014 16:25:15=[36.6, 33.42, 40.45], 07/30/2014 08:43:57=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 08/12/2014 22:00:52=[77.99, 74.1, 80.12], 08/12/2014 21:19:48=[56.91, 63.23, 52.42], 07/23/2014 13:37:46=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 08/11/2014 17:35:21=[40.9, 43.83, 38.34]}
```

key is date, value is array list..

i want to extract each data in different variable

ex:

```
var i=09/02/2014 15:36:25;
var i1= 33.82;
var i2 =33.42;
var i3= 40.83;
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Please get a basic grasp of computer programming before coming here. Once you do, also make sure to read the [faq] to ask proper questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, your data isn't in valid JSON format. You should verify your data before trying to deal with it (for example by using [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)).

Assuming your data is in fact (I don't care about the `date` key in `string` format):

```
var data = {"09/02/2014 15:36:25":[33.82, 33.42, 40.83], "08/11/2014 16:25:15":[36.6, 33.42, 40.45], "07/30/2014 08:43:57":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "08/12/2014 22:00:52":[77.99, 74.1, 80.12], "08/12/2014 21:19:48":[56.91, 63.23, 52.42], "07/23/2014 13:37:46":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "08/11/2014 17:35:21":[40.9, 43.83, 38.34]};
```

You can process it by using (for example):

```
for(var key in data) {
    var value = data[key]; // value is you array, you can use it as usual.
    alert("key = " + key + ", value = " + value + ", value.length = " + value.length);    
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7e5s1Lv/)

By the way, this doesn't rely to java or html, these tags are unnecessary.

And be more conscientious next time.